# match two or more object from differents models with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have 2 model:

```
class User
 include Mongoid::Document
 field :email, :type => String, :null => false, :default => ""
 .
 .
end

class Admin
 include Mongoid::Document
 field :email, :type => String, :null => false, :default => ""
 .
 .
end
```

I want with a mongoid query find all users have a equal email in `Admin` model, something like:

```
User.where(:email => {exist_admin_class?})
```

This is possible? Or I have make a relationship between two model with a `has_one User` and `belongs_to Admin`

What is the best way to do this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: doesnt feel like that can be done in mongodb even with  relation you have to fire a join query I guess mongodb doesnot have a join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, MongoDB doesnt support cross collection queries. But it isnt necessary, especially not in this requirement. I would suggest using inheritance for that:

[mongoid HowTo](http://two.mongoid.org/docs/documents/inheritance.html)

Why: Just because admins are a special kind of users.